# Chrome doesn't support this query string

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, query-string, cross-browser

I am extract data from a link, http://safalra.com/web-design/javascript/parsing-query-strings/. It works fine in Firefox, but Google Chrome didn't support this functionality. Is there a better way or alternative procedure to extract the query string contents?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _url = window.location
    alert(_url);
    var queryData = parseQueryString(_url.toString());
    var p = queryData['http://localhost/new_logic/test.php?a'];
    alert(queryData);
    var q = queryData['b'];
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parseQueryString at http://safalra.com/web-design/javascript/parsing-query-strings/ has some bugs:

- Multiple `+`s are not replaced with space.
- Multiple unescaped equal-signs causes content to be lost.
- Empty input results in an object with key "".
- Multiple empty keys isn't discarded

In the function below, the bugs above have been removed and it has been tested in Firefox 3, Internet Explorer 7, Opera 9 and Google Chrome 1.

```
function parseQueryString(input){
    var out={}, decode=decodeURIComponent, s=input||location.search||"",
        kv=("?"===s.charAt(0)?s.slice(1):s).replace(/\+/g," ").split(/[&;]/g),
        idx=-1,key,value;
    while(++idx<kv.length){
        if (kv[idx]==="") continue;
        value=kv[idx].split("=");
        key=decode(value.shift());
        (out[key]||(out[key]=[])).push(decode(value.join("=")));
    }
    return out;
}
```

The function above (and the original) expects only the query part of the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator): from the question mark to the end of the string or to the first #. If no argument is supplied it will automatically extract the query part from the URL of the browser's current location.

The result is an object with the keys from the query string, and the value of all keys is an array of all the values.

```
var data = parseQueryString("?a=test1&a=test2&b=test3");

//Result of data:
{
    a:["test1","test2"],
    b:["test3"]
}
```

Some examples:

```
// Alert all values of the a key:
if (data.a && data.a.length) {
  for (var i=0;i<data.a.length;++i)
    alert(data.a[i]);
}

// Get the first value of a-key:
var value_a = data.a && data.a[0];

// Get the first value of a-key or default:
var value_a = data.a && data.a[0] || "default";
```

Answer (score 6):

The `parseQueryString()` function created by the author of the page you linked to obviously invokes some JavaScript code that does not run on Chrome.

This does not mean that Chrome does not support QueryStrings in general. It appears that you have assumed that the `parseQueryString()` function is global in nature and is inherently built into all browsers. On the contrary, it is a custom function built by the author.

You would best be advised to email the author using the contact form on the page, or drill into the JavaScript file and find out exactly what is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you used 'parseQuerySTring' wouldn't return anything for a in `http://localhost/new_logic/test.php?a`, because 'a' has no value. Perhaps you should try `http://localhost/new_logic/test.php?a=1&b=2&c=3`. Now queryData.a should return 1, queryData.b 2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

The script seems to expect only the search part as input, but it works for me on the last version of Chrome.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var _url = window.location.search;
     alert(_url);
     var queryData = parseQueryString(_url.toString());
     var p = queryData['a'];
     alert(p);
     var q = queryData['b'];
     alert(q);
 </script>
```

Displays

```
?a=aval&b=bval
aval
bval
```